# Lightning Flow issue?! Not working properly

Tags: lightning, lightning-web-components, visual-workflow, app-builder

I have created a Lightning Flow, where I pass recordId to custom LWC component.

When I save it, i get following warning - (**Although Lightning Runtime is enabled**)
[image]

Then when I add my Flow to a record page, it says - (**This is a placeholder. Flows don't run in canvas**)

[image]

Then when I go out & check in Record page, a static/dummy version of my LWC component is present..!!!
None of the functionalities on that page work. Just static HTML version.

Can someone please help me..!!

I am stuck.

Comment: Why exactly are you trying to run the LWC in a flow on the Record page rather than just putting the LWC on the record page? You can specify the `<targetConfig targets="lightning__RecordPage">`  in the LWC and that'll give you access to the recordId in the component.

It also might help if you share some of your LWC code since the issue might be there.

Comment: @stackasaur There are many LWC's components to be showed one after another. I am currently showing on the record page itself directly. But I need to show them as a survey form.

Comment: Neither of those warning messages is likely related to your problem. What is the behavior that you're expecting to see that's not there?
First, verify that your flow works as expected when you run it from the Flow Builder, to isolate that the screen component is working properly. Did you create a variable called 'recordId" in Flow and set it to be "Available for Input"? That's a common thing to miss. Run the Flow in Debug mode and paste in the recordId of the record from the record page.